# Recognize the backspace and spacebar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when a user clicks the spacebar or backspace I need to create a variable that stores the action so I can use it to manipulate an array. I want the backspace to delete a value in an array and the spacebar to create a space. How can I do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 8){
       // user has pressed backspace
       array.pop();
   }
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // user has pressed space
       array.push('');
   }
});
```

Comment: what is array.pop? does that delete the last value in the array?

Comment: Yeah. You can also search for an element inside array, and delete that one.

Comment: It still is not recognizing the backspace

Comment: Backspace key code is 8. To get the key code of any key on the keyboard, simply put an input element somewhere, bind to `keyup` event and write the `e.keyCode` to the console (or alert it).

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('#inputid').bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                alert('space');
            }
            if (e.which == 8) {//backspace
                alert('back space');
            }
    });


    });
```

Comment: It still is not recognizing the backspace

Answer (score 4):

**It scrolled down the page!**
I wanted to use the space bar key to trigger a function as:

```
$("#org").on("keydown", function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            my_func();//The function executes but the page is scrolled down
        }
});
```

Now I have changed the code and added **return false** and it worked perfectly as I don't want space in typed word as well.

```
$("#org").on("keydown", function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            my_func();
            return false;//to fix the scrolling down on space bar key press
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gSWwp/1/

I call the method e.preventDefault(); for ignore the default event associated to the keypress for a field.
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for backspace because the keypress event is only fired for printable chars. You have to use keyup / keydown instead.
But be aware that keyup / keypress will always give you the keycode for the uppercase form of the key pressed whether keypress care about case sensitive and give you the correct key code. You can check in the keyup / keydown handler if the shiftkey is pressed via e.shiftkey which return a boolean. If e.shiftkey is false you have to add 32 to e.which to get the correct keycode. I think this is what is done in the keypress event.